# ¿Error con el "EventHandler"

Tags: c#

Básicamente estoy haciendo un método para agarrar un dato de un datagrid, el método lo tengo pero en el .designer me marca el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy consiente que es por esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero es que lo ocupo para el método si no el "columIndex" y el "rowIndex" no me funcionaria
¿alguna solución?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas usando el evento `Click` al parecer de un control `Button` pero al crearlo le estas agregando como argumento una referencia a un procedimiento que no se corresponde con el argumento aceptado por el evento `Click`, el argumento aceptado por este evento, es un delegado que tiene la siguiente sintaxis `private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`, esa sintaxis hay que respetarla, no puedes cañonearla y pasarle otros argumentos que no acepta. Si quieres  usar este evento, tendras que usar algo parecido a los siguiente:

```
 this.btnEliminar.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnEliminar_Click);
       private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //Aqui colocar tu codigo.

        }
```

Logicamente aquí no podrias usar `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` ni sus propiedades `e.RowIndex` y `e.ColumnIndex`, pues en ese entorno no existen; para lograr algo asi, deberias usar el evento `CellClick` de tu `DataGridView` `dgReservaciones`, el cual seria lanzado al hacer Click sobre una celda del control `dgReservaciones`, lo que quedaria como sigue.

```
        this.dgReservaciones.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgReservaciones_CellClick);

   private void dgReservaciones_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dgReservaciones.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
    }
```

A por ultimo un comentario, las preguntas con código en imagenes no son muy bien recibidas, pues obligas a quien desee responder a teclear todo desde cero, es mejor recibido, colocar el codigo como texto, que permita copiar y pegar, tenlo en cuenta para proximas preguntas, esta es realmente sencilla, no fue mucho el codigo que hubo que teclear.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí podríamos acortarlo a esto:

```
this.dgReservaciones.CellClick += dgReservaciones_CellClick;
```

Ya que el método cumple con las condiciones del delegado.